# This jquery code working only for first item and i am stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery

So..i have jquery code that allow me to send clicked link directly outside the form
My code

```
$(function(){
    $("#link-id").click(function(){
       $('#content').val($(this).html()); 
         $('#main_input').submit();
       return false;
    });
  });
```

and this is clicked link (dynamic link)
and when i clicked on this link they passed to input filed and going to content

```
<a href="#" id="link-id">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '</a></div>
```

My Form

```
<form id="main_input" name="chat_data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="content"  maxlength="300" id="content" placeholder="Write Your Message.." autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

And My problem showing here
in fact is 2 issues

1. this code working only for first video showing in the result
2. this code working only in chrome console not in the main.js file
3. This Video explain exactly what i said..sorry for my english
4. https://streamable.com/u8k6u

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID (`link-id`)?

Comment: Your code sets up a click event handler for the element with the `id` of `link-id` and no other. IDs must be unique.

Comment: every video showing from results have this <a href="#" id="link-id">

Comment: So you can't have that, ID MUST BE UNIQUE. Change `id="link-id"` to `class="link-id"` and in the event you need to change `$("#link-id").click(function(){` to `$(".link-id").click(function(){`

Comment: big thanks..the first problem is 50% solved by change from id to class..now i need to run code in main.js file not in chrome console because still not working inside main.js and also this working only for first page ..when i change page inside form results.. the code is died

Comment: You probably not using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - It will probably work if you change `$(".link-id").click(function(){` to `$("body").on("click", ".link-id", function(){` (Check the link in my comment to learn more)

Comment: finaaaaly is working man...i love you.. :) ❤❤❤❤